# SQL - Tables creation - 1 to 3

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like this setup :

```
TABLE [group] :
[group_id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) --as pkey,
[member_one] INT NOT NULL --as fkey [member].[member_id],
[member_two] INT NULL --as fkey [member].[member_id],
[member_three] INT NULL --as fkey [member].[member_id],
...

TABLE [member] :
[member_id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) --as pkey,
[group_id] INT NOT NULL --as fkey [group].[group_id],
...
```

With words :
I have groups with members.
Each member has one and only one group.

**EDIT 1 :**
Each group has at least one member, and the member_one is the leader, who can't be changed.
Each group may have an infinite number of members, but only one to three (leader included) can be something we'll call "the head-staff".
**---**

How could I do if I want to create a group and a leader in the same time ?
I can't create a group without the leader, and I can't create the leader without creating the group.
I don't want to remove the "NOT NULL" in both tables.

I don't know how to use stored proc, so if it uses it (I don't say it should), do it easy !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use following data logical model:

```
Group(GroupID - PK, ...)
GroupMemberType(GroupMemberTypeID - PK, Name, IsHeadStaff)
    Example: 
        1 - Leader - 1
        2 - Power member - 1
        3 - Standard member - 2
    Reason: this way we can add easily [new] types
Member(MemberID - PK, ..., GroupID - FK, GroupMemberTypeID - FK)
```

If one group can have only leader then I would create an unique [filtered index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) thus (assuming that GroupMemberTypeID = 1 -- Leader

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX INF_Member_GroupID_GroupMemberTypeID1
ON dbo.Member (GroupID)
WHERE GroupMemberTypeID = 1 -- Leader
```

To check if current inserted and/or updated member are assigned to a group and for current group(s) there are max 3 head staff member I would use an `AFTER INSERT/UPDATE` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgIU_Member_CheckMax3HeadStaff
ON dbo.Member
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

IF EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Member m JOIN dbo.GroupMemberType gmt ON m.GroupMemberTypeID = gmt.GroupMemberTypeID
    WHERE m.GroupID IN (SELECT i.GroupID FROM inserted i)
    AND gmt.IsHeadStaff = 1
    GROUP BY m.GroupID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
)
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
    RAISERROR('One group can have maximum three head staff members,', 16, 1)
END

END
```

Comment: It seems to work perfectly for the leader, but what about the two other staff members ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem your describing is simply because you're violating relational data modeling principals.
You don't need to have the members in both tables, that's just repeating data for no reason.

```
TABLE [group] :
[group_id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) --as pkey,

...

TABLE [member] :
[member_id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) --as pkey,
[group_id] INT NOT NULL --as fkey [group].[group_id],
[isLeader] BIT NOT NULL
...
```

You create the group in [group] then add the members with that group to the [member] table. This makes it easier to query, easier to manage and fits within the RDBMS convetions. With a simple Join you get all the information you need. IF your groups change to 4 members you're fine.

Comment: I have forgotten something, and editted my post. Actually, there is a lot of members, but three is particular are shown in the group, while the others aren't.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution which is great to me :

- Create a Function which returns how many leader there is in my group
- Add a check and look if the previous Function returns 0
- Create another Function which returns how many staff these are in my group
- Add another check and look if this second Function returns < 3

Comment: Please avoid using UDF within CHECK constraints especially if that UDF read data from tables: it can return false positives and also it is a performance bottleneck.